# Function keys F5 and F6 not working properly on macOs when using Keychron keyboard

Tags: macos, intellij-idea, keyboard-shortcuts

I'm trying to use the refactoring rename shortcut on IntelliJ (`Shift + F6`). However, it doesn't work. I'm using macOS and a Keychron K8 keyboard. I noticed that F5 is not recognized either.

Comment: Amazing, this is the exact issue I was facing with my K3, right down to the IntelliJ keyboard shortcut!

Answer (score 64, accepted):

I just found the solution: pressing `fn + K + C` for 3s, the Keychron keyboard flashes 3 times, then the function of keys f5 and f6 will switch to the normal function on macOS.

Source: [Keychron news](https://www.keychron.com/blogs/news/keychron-keyboards-shortcuts-introduction)

Comment: source appears to be: https://www.keychron.com/blogs/news/keychron-keyboards-shortcuts-introduction

Comment: amazing, thanks for the hint, just face this issue on the new keyboard